# Why is my Hello World Program failing?

Tags: loops, brainfuck

So, I handwrote this program in [BrainFuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck):

```
+++++++++++++++++[>++++>++++>++++>++++>++>+++++>++++>++++>++++>++++<<<<<<<<<<-]
>++++.>+.>++++++++..>+++++++++++.>--.>++.>+++++++++++.>++++++++++++++.>++++++++.>.
```

and it displays exactly what I wanted:

```
HELLO WORLD
```

But then I wanted it to display `HELLO WORLD` five times in a row, so I wrapped it in a loop:

```
+++++[>
+++++++++++++++++[>++++>++++>++++>++++>++>+++++>++++>++++>++++>++++<<<<<<<<<<-]
>++++.>+.>++++++++..>+++++++++++.>--.>++.>+++++++++++.>++++++++++++++.>++++++++.>.
<<<<<<<<<<<-]
```

I expected it to have this output:

```
HELLO WORLDHELLO WORLDHELLO WORLDHELLO WORLDHELLO WORLD
```

But it's displaying this instead:

```
HELLO WORLDŠ˜˜ž@®ž¤˜ˆØÏääí`íöäÌ 00<€\<H0hY||‹ ³‹š|T
```

What am I doing wrong with my loop? Why isn't it displaying `HELLO WORLD` five times in a row, as expected?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget any 0 termination character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't looping over "HELLO WORLD"' you're looping over the code that creates it...

You have two options, either zero everything out as you move back using [-]<, that works with your current code because it will return the array elements to thier initial state, and when you rerun your code  it will be have the same values, i.e:

http://ideone.com/GjAp8

```
+++++[>
+++++++++++++++++[>++++>++++>++++>++++>++>+++++>++++>++++>++++>++++<<<<<<<<<<-]
>++++.>+.>++++++++..>+++++++++++.>--.>++.>+++++++++++.>++++++++++++++.>++++++++.>.
[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]
<-]
```

or use this (don't print the array as you fill it in, wait until it is created and then do it)

http://ideone.com/iWs8X

```
+++++++++++++++++[>++++>++++>++++>++++>++>+++++>++++>++++>++++>++++<<<<<<<<<<-]
>++++>+>++++++++>+++++++++++>-->++>+++++++++++>++++++++++++++>++++++++>
<<<<<<<<<<
 +++++[>.>.>..>.>.>.>.>.>.>.<<<<<<<<<<-]
```